# How to use REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK in C# Registry class

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, symlink, registrykey

I want to open a registry key that is a symbolic link.
[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw#parameters) I need to use `REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK` to open it.
I searched for an option to add it to the `OpenSubKey` function but I didn't find an option. There are only fiver overload functions but none of them allow to add an optional parameter:

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(string name)
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(string name, bool writable)
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(string name, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(string name, RegistryRights rights)
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(string name, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistryRights rights)
```

The only way I can think of is to use p\invoke but maybe I am missing it and there is an option in C# classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the normal `RegistryKey` functions. Having checked in [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/src/Microsoft/Win32/RegistryKey.Windows.cs), it seems that the `ulOptions` parameter is always passed as `0`.

The only way is to call `RegOpenKeyEx` yourself, and pass the resulting `SafeRegistryHandle` to `RegistryKey.FromHandle`

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
```

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int RegOpenKeyExW(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, String lpSubKey,
    int ulOptions, int samDesired, out SafeRegistryHandle hkResult);

public static RegistryKey OpenSubKeySymLink(this RegistryKey key, string name, RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.ReadKey, RegistryView view = 0)
{
    const int REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK = 0x0008;
    var error = RegOpenKeyExW(key.Handle, name, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, ((int)rights) | ((int)view), out var subKey);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        subKey.Dispose();
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    return RegistryKey.FromHandle(subKey);  // RegistryKey will dispose subKey
}
```

It is an extension function, so you can call it on either an existing sub-key, or on one of the main keys, such as [`Registry.CurrentUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser?view=net-6.0). Don't forget to put a `using` on the returned `RegistryKey`:

```cs
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKeySymLink(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\myKey", RegistryRights.ReadKey))
{
    // do stuff with key
}
```