# How to initialize RegistryKey variable

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, registrykey

I have a function (`OpenSubKeySymLink`) that receives this kind of variable: `this RegistryKey key`.
I don't know how to initialize it and pass it to the function.

```cs
public static RegistryKey OpenSubKeySymLink(this RegistryKey key, string name, RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.ReadKey, RegistryView view = 0)
{
    var error = RegOpenKeyExW(key.Handle, name, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, ((int)rights) | ((int)view), out var subKey);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        subKey.Dispose();
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    return RegistryKey.FromHandle(subKey);  // RegistryKey will dispose subKey
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegistryKey key;  // how to initialize it?
    OpenSubKeySymLink(key, @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\myKey", RegistryRights.ReadKey, 0);
}
```

Comment: Looks like an extension method. In which case you don't explicitly pass the first parameter, in this instance `key`. That's implicitly passed with the object you call the method on.

Comment: Use one of the static members of the `Registry` class, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize, I didn't fully explain how to use this code in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70642026/14868997).

I wrote it as an extension, so you can call it on either an existing sub-key, or on one of the main keys, such as [`Registry.CurrentUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser?view=net-6.0).

You would use it like this for example:

```cs
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKeySymLink(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\myKey", RegistryRights.ReadKey))
{
    // do stuff with key
}
```

You can obviously still use it as a non-extension function

```cs
using (var key = OpenSubKeySymLink(Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\myKey", RegistryRights.ReadKey))
{
    // do stuff with key
}
```

- Note the optional parameters, which means that some parameters don't need  to be passed as they have defaults.
- Note the use of `using` on the returned `key`, in order to dispose it correctly.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation, it works. I didn't want to comment this on the previous question as I considered it as a separate question that can maybe help other. Thank you!